Как построить OLAP отчёты на основе данных из Odata?
Мне необходимо настроить построение OLAP отчётов, с помощью надстройки Power Pivot в Excel. Я изучил всё описание на сайте Microsoft, но не нашел как реализовать построение отчётов не на основе листов excel, а на основе данных Odata. Т.е. нужно, чтобы данные для построения отчёта  собирались напрямую из OdataFreed, а не из листов.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, кто то настраивал подобное? Если настраивали, то как это сделать?
